# Reference Cell from closed Workbook VBA (with error check and relative path)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Going to reword this as it was pretty poor.

Here is some code I got from stackoverflow to take data from a cell within a closed workbook, it works perfect

Sub PullValue()
    Dim PATH, FILENAME, SHEETNAME, CELL

```
PATH = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\"
FILENAME = "Book1.xlsm"
SHEETNAME = "Sheet1"
CELL = "A1"

With Range("A2")
    .Formula = "='" & PATH & "[" & FILENAME & "]" & SHEETNAME & "'!" & CELL & ""
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

End Sub

However. I am trying to replace the PATH "C:..." with a relative link. I have tried many forms, i.e. 'ThisWorkbook.Path' but nothing seems to work, so I'm obviously adding the code in wrong as I'm not really a VBA user.

If anyone has any tips it'd be greatly appreciated and bonus points if you can tell me how to ignore errors also. I would like the CELL to return a blank if the SHEETNAME does not exist.

Cheers

:)

Comment: Indirect references *require* the referenced workbook to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see no reason why it wouldn't work, however, did you remember after `thisworkbook.path`to add another "\"? What do you actually mean by saying relative paths?

Comment: Thanks. That was it. So the final line was
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
and this worked a treat :D
By relative path I meant from the current folder rather than from the root.

Now I just need to figure out how to ignore any errors

Comment: on error capturing you can read up here: [On Error Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)